# Java: listening to a single port with more threads vs listening to multiple ports

Tags: java, sockets, networking, network-programming, port

Say I have a Java program listening to a port 8001, consuming and doing some work off of the message
Is there a theoretical max on the throughput of bits being processed by a program on that port? ie you dedicate a thread to that port and you can scale by adding more threads to listen to that port? Is there a limit on how many threads you can dedicate to that port?

Now, if there is indeed a theoretical max on how much you can scale by throwing more threads at a particular port, could this be overcome by having the program listen to additional ports, 8001 and 8002 and have 2x more threads? Can your program serve twice as more requests now?

or these throughput on a port vs ports is a non-issued that the throughput of bits coming into the host limited by the NIC?

Comment: No, there is no theoretical maximum.

Comment: @user207421 so i can scale by throwing more threads at the port. no need to split the traffic to additional port to increase the number of requests a host can serve?

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Comment: @user207421 oh okay, that was not obvious to me and hence the question

Answer (score -1):

You can serve as many concurrent connections as you like on the same socket(***). You can assign a thread to each connection, but keep in mind that in Java each thread consumes about 2MB.

And since we are talking about scaling, adding threads doesn’t magically add cores to your CPU.

(***) There’s a theoretical limit, as the number of possible ip adresses multiplied by the number of possible source ports is finite, but you will run out of memory before reaching it.

Comment: On the same *port.*

Comment: @Mateusz Stefek i am referring the the amount of bits coming into the same port. For example if my host is connected via 1GB ethernet, it is possible for the host to consume up to all of 1GB from a single port?